# Как записать результаты парсинга python в json? (windows)

Tags: python, json, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
products = soup.findAll("div", class_="tovar")
products_json = [products]

for product in products:
    try:
        product_name = product.find("p")  # вытащил значение из тега по атрибуту
        product_price = product.find("div", class_="tovar-price").text  # вытащил цену
        print(f'{product_name["name"]} | {product_price}')
    except Exception as ex:
        print()

products_json.append({
    'product_name': product_name, #вот здесь что-то идёт не так
    'product_price': product_price, #и тут тоже
})
with open("products.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f: #файл создаётся, но пустой
    json.dump(products_json, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: Может `products_json.append` нужно поместить **внутрь цикла** (и внутрь `try`)?

Comment: уже и так этак попробовал, но всё равно данные не записываются в файл

Comment: Смотрели, что в `products_json` - тоже пусто? `print(products_json)`

Comment: При print(products_json) почему то показывает все div-блоки. Сам файл products_json создаётся, но он пустой и весит 0 кб. Совсем не могу понять в чём дело(

Comment: Может вы не в том каталоге файл смотрите и это какой-то старый файл, а не новый? Дата-время у файла свежие? Попробуйте на всякий случай напечатать текущий каталог: `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Выводит в терминале:
Жевательная резинка DIROL 13,6гр Арбузная свежесть 1/30шт(57626543) | 39.9 руб.
C:\Users\SERGEY\PycharmProjects\ТЕСТ
Жевательная резинка DIROL 13,6гр Ледяная мята 1/30шт(7622210617828) | 39.9 руб.
C:\Users\SERGEY\PycharmProjects\ТЕСТ
Каждый раз файл удаляю, потом запускаю - создаётся новый файл - который совершенно пустой

Comment: Может я словарь не так создаю?

Comment: А смотрите файл чем? Может просмотрщик кодировку UTF8 не понимает? Странно это всё. То, что в списке должно нормально записаться в файл.

Comment: Просматриваю файл в pycharm, но не меняет того факта, что файл весит 0 килобайт. При выводе json.dump(products_json, w, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4) из try и цикла, выходит ошибка что не распознается метод "w" и файл вообще не создаётся. В цикле и в try - создаётся, но пустой.